# How to show the particular role users in dropdown using yii2?

Tags: php, yii2, yii-components

## This is my view

```
'promoter_id' => [ 
    'type' => Form::INPUT_DROPDOWN_LIST,
    'options' => ['prompt' => '--'.Yii::t ( 'app', 'Ventor Type' ).'--',],
    'items' => ArrayHelper::map (
        User::find ()->orderBy ( 'username')->where(['user_type_id' => [13]])->asArray ()->all (),
        'id', 
        'username' 
    )
]
```

**What i did?**
show the users filtered by `user_type_id = 13`.
`user_type_id=13` means the users are promoters.

**What i want?**
I want to show the users like below sql query using `ArrayHelper::map`.

```
SELECT u.username 
    FROM tbl_user u,tbl_user_type t
    where u.user_type_id = t.id and t.type='promoter';
```

Comment: What database are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using mysql you can simply use an [`innerJoin`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-query.html#innerJoin%28%29-detail):

```
User::find()
    ->select(['user.id', 'user.username'])
    ->innerJoin('user_type', 'user_type.id = user.id')
    ->where(['user_type.type' => 'promoter'])
    ->orderBy('username')
    ->asArray()
    ->all(),
```

If you have a relation between `user` and `user_type` you can use [`joinWith`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-activequery.html#joinWith()-detail) instead, which handles the join type and the join condition for you:

```
User::find()
    ->select(['user.id', 'user.username'])
    ->joinWith('userType', true)
    ->where(['userType.type' => 'promoter'])
    ->orderBy('username')
    ->asArray ()
    ->all (),
```